# Vaadin Grid Table: how to draw border for empty cells?

Tags: java, css, grid, vaadin, vaadin8

I'm using vaadins grid. The grid has a fixed height, so the grid is not always full of data. If it is not full then it stops with the line in the middle where the data stops. 
However, I want the middle line to go all the way down.

it looks like now:

[image: treegrid]

How can I realize this?
I use Vaadin 8.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Try you look [here](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples)

Comment: @Jeremy there is a Border-left for the cells, but when i have no cell there ist no border-left and the line in the middle ends.
.v-treegrid-cell {
  background-color: #ededed !important;
  border-bottom: none !important;
 }

Comment: vaadin version might be helpful

Comment: I think you answered your own question here.  There are no cells, so there is no way to style them.  I don't think there is a way to "fill" the visual screenspace with phantom cells out of the box (except of course adding empty data, but you might have to guess how much)